# jQuery html() ... styling not read from css file

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I have a DIV which is written via an ajax call to a perl script through jQuery - and then on success is written with .html()

The html that is written contains several DIVs ... each of which has an ID and an entry in a css file for styling.

The problem I have is that the styling is ignored when the text is written.

Example:

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css" />
...
<div id="CONTAINER"></div>
```

javascript:

```
$.ajax({
  url: './GetInfo.pl',
  success: function(data) {
  alert(data);             // to check the right html is returned - and it is!
    $('#CONTAINER').html(data);
  } 
});
```

CSS:

```
body { color: black; font-size: 10pt; }

#childDiv1 { color: #ffffff; font-size: 12pt; }
#childDiv2 { color: #ffff00; font-size: 14pt; }
#childDiv3 { color: #ff00ff; font-size: 16pt; }
```

Perl:

```
print <<HTML;
Content-type: text/html

  <div id="childDiv1">Info 1</div>
  <div id="childDiv2">Info 2</div>
  <div id="childDiv3">Info 3</div>
HTML
```

.... all the DIVs have the correct text but the styling is taken from BODY entry in the CSS file and not new DIV entry.

Comment: What browser are you having this issue in?

Comment: I tried Chrome, FF and Safari

Comment: It's not a duplicate because my css file is already in the html from the start - the added html from ajax just needs to use it.

Comment: It should work as you've written it. CSS applies to all DOM elements, whether they're in the original HTML or added dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh dear .. it was an error in the CSS file ... nowhere near the lines I had problems with - which was why I missed it .. and nothing that affected any other part of the application.

I apologise for wasting people's time.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the dataType attribute in your ajaxRequest to html.

```
dataType : 'html'
```